# Changing route parameter without reload

Tags: angular

I know there are a couple of similar postings on this topic but none of them helped me so far.

I have a route path:

/main/:object/:id?params=...

So I may navigate to /main/account/-1?returnUrl="..."

The -1 indicates to my application this is a new record and as soon as the record is save to the db I will have a real id (for example id=123)

Now I want to change the URL to /main/account/123?returnUrl="..." so I have a proper navigation when I go into some details of my new record and have to return to this page. The question therefore is: how can I replace one route param but keep the rest identical (other route params unchanged, query params still existing) and do not reload the page again?

I am using the latest version of Angular.

Rgds
Michael

Comment: Can we see you code ?

Comment: Did you use `HttpParams` for your query string ?

Comment: is it same component or not ?

Comment: Hi, I have no code for this so far. I know I can change the URL without reload using this.location.go(newUrl) after I save the record and know the new id. But I dont know how to build this new URL.

I guess there is a way to achieve this with createUrlTree() something like:

newUrl = this.router.createUrlTree([currentParamsObj], {relativeTo: this.url.path(), queryParams: this.route.snapshot.queryParams }).toString();

But this didnt work so far.

Comment: Yes - same component. Just need to rebuild the URL and change one route param and call go()

Comment: using `Location` will update the router parameters, however the component will not update if you have any kind of binding to the params in your template

Comment: No need for updating any bindings - thats already all handled. But how would I use Location to change the URL with the changed route param?